# how to make new folder php variable

Tags: php

I make inside `root/` (http docs) new folder  `example/`

Inside `example/` folder add `cache.php` page

PHP code from `cache.php`:

```
/* Cache file to either load or create */
  $cachefile = $cachedir . md5($page) . 'cache/' . $cacheext;
  $cachefile_created = ((@file_exists($cachefile)) and ($ignore_page === false)) ? @filemtime($cachefile) : 0;
  @clearstatcache();
```

I have a problem line:

```
$cachefile = $cachedir . md5($page) . 'cache/' . $cacheext;
```

Variable  `/./`  make html file outside `example/`

Inside `example/`  new folder  `/cache`.

Who is absolute path? Example:

`/cache/` or  `./cache`  or  `/./cache`?

Comment: Please clarify: What is the value of `$cacheDir`? What result are you getting for `$cachefile`? What do you expect?

Comment: /* Cache file to either load or create */
  $cachefile = $cachedir . md5($page) . 'cache/' . $cacheext;
  $cachefile_created = ((@file_exists($cachefile)) and ($ignore_page === false)) ? @filemtime($cachefile) : 0;
  @clearstatcache();
 
  /* Is cache file still fresh? If so, serve it */
 
  if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
  include($cachefile);
  exit;
  }

Comment: /*Extension to give cached files (usually cache, htm, txt) */
  $cacheext = 'html';

Comment: Please don't use answers and comments for additional information, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./cache` is a relative path

for example : if you are in the `/dir`  directory, and your variable holds as `$var = './path/to'` then it means `/dir/path/to`

any directory which starts with a `/` it is absolute path. for example if you are in `/dir` directory and your variable holds as `$var = '/path/to'` then it means `/path/to` it is not related with `/dir` directory anymore.

`./` this stands for the current directory  `./` == `./././././`
`/./` this is root directory `/` first slash is the root directory and `./` is the relative path to root directory, you are saying root directory's current directory which means the root directory.

Comment: httpdocs/example/cache.php   cache.php generate html file outeside example/.

Comment: i want  genarate  html file  into to cache/ folder  etc. example/cache/demo.html

Comment: just add echo $cachefile; exit; and check it, is the directory your desired directory ? You may change your line to this $cachefile = __DIR__  . '/' . $cachedir . md5($page) . 'cache/' . $cacheext;

Comment: check this out . http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/howto-use-php-magic-constants-file-dir-function-class-method-line-namespace/

Comment: CODE ITS OK I FINDE ERROR PROBLEM  THANK YOU FOR ALL  $cachefile = $cachedir.'/cache/'. md5($page) . '.' . $cacheext;

Answer (score 0):

problem this is folder  example/cache.php  genarete  html file outside  example/

httpdocs/example/

i have make new folder   path  httpdocs/example/cache/

problem line:

$cachefile = $cachedir . md5($page) . 'cache/' . $cacheext;
Variable  /./ make html file outside example/

Inside example/ new folder  /cache.

Who is absolute path? Example:

/cache/ or  ./cache or  /./cache?